# In cl-ppcre, how can I discover the number of register groups in a regex?

Tags: regex, common-lisp

Using cl-ppcre, I want to discover the number of register groups in a regex, without performing any match. Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the regular expression as a string, you can use `cl-ppcre:parse-string` to convert it to a sexp you can examine for occurrences of `:REGISTER`, e.g.

```
(count :register (alexandria:flatten (ppcre:parse-string "^\\d (\\S+|(x|y))")))
```

If it's already been created with `create-scanner`, I don't think you have many options; that object is an opaque closure.